# Text alignment issue- H4 content displays to the right of images

Tags: html, css

Any tips on how to align the H4 text on the projects section so that it appears beneath the images rather than to right of them? This doesn't appear to correspond to the HTML whereby the H4 follows the img tag. In order to align items along the the horizontal and vertical axis I have been using css grids.

Many thanks!

```css
   
/*Reset */

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

body,p,a,ul,li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;

}

/*Base styles*/


body {
    background: var(--secondary);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Rubik-VariableFont_wght';
}

.button {
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary);
    color: var(--primary);
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: inline-block;
}

.button:hover {
    color: #222;
    background: var(--primary);
}

input,textarea {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    padding: 10px 16px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #9893d8;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}

/*Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family:'Rubik-VariableFont_wght';
    src:url('/fonts/Rubik-VariableFont_wght.ttf')

}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    color: #0077b3;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p,a,li {
   color: ##0077b3;
}

h1,h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size:1.6em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.leading {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}


/*Mobile/default styles*/

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat (8,1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}

 

#portfolio {
    background-image: url('images/spaceimg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

#portfolio h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.projects a {
    grid-column: 1/9;
    margin: 20px 0;
    display: flex;
}

.projects a *{
    margin: 0 20px;
    max-width: 40%;
    align-self: center;
}

.projects h4 {
    color: #0077b3;
}

.projects img {
    box-shadow: 30px #222;
}

.projects img {
    border-radius: 60px;
}

   

    .projects {
        margin-top:40px;
    }

    .projects a {
        grid-column: span 4;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .projects .row-one {
        grid-row:1;
    }

    .projects img {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .projects .row-three {
      grid-column: 3/7;
    }

    .projects a * {
        margin: 10px auto;
        max-width:30%;
        height: 120px;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Example site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css">
</head>

<body>

    <section id="portfolio">
        <!--Project section-->
        <h3>Example site</h3>
        <div class="grid projects">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/image3.png" alt="shuttle-image1" >
                <h4>Space race one</h4>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/image4.png" alt="shuttle-image2">
                <h4>Space race two</h4>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="row-three">
                <img src="images/image5.png" alt="shuttle-image3">
                <h4>Space race three</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are your expected result, can you show some image. Why 8 columns in grid?

Comment: `.projects a { display:flex; }` creates two columns: one for the `img` , one for the `h4`